# Terraform- How to iterate through a list of maps without making duplicates?

Tags: list, terraform, maps, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

- I have a list that contains the names (strings) of the secret scopes that I want to create

Example:

```
ss-list = ["name1", "name2"]
```

- I have a map that contains 2 objects that are applied to each name in my ss-list.
  Example:

```
 keyvault-map = {

    kv1 = {
      id = "abc",
      dns-name = "123"
    },

    kv2 = {
      id = "def",
      dns-name = "456"
    }
  }
```

- So for each item in ss-list I need to pull the 2 items inside the map and append to make 1 list.
- The end result list that I desire to be returned is...

```
[

  {
    "keyvault-id" = "abc"

    "keyvault-uri" = "123"

    "name" = "name1"
  },

  {

    "keyvault-id" = "def"

    "keyvault-uri" = "456"

    "name" = "name2"

  }

]
```

- I'm looking for how I can iterate through this list and map and return my desired list (with no duplicates).

Comment: Your question is not clear. What duplicates? Your code does not contain any? Also maps in TF do not have order, so exactly how do you want to match the values in map and your list? If you rely on the apparent ordering of items, you will get into issues, even if it may seem it works.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. So essentially I am trying to create multiple databricks secret scope resources using for_each. This resource requires 3 attributes: name (Which I have in a list in my variable.tf of my databricks module), resource_id and dns_name (aka "keyvault-metadata", which I also have in my variable.tf as a map that I outputted from my keyvault module). Now I need to combine that list of names and map of keyvault-metadata into one structure to iterate over and create the multiple resources using for_each in the databricks.tf module. @Marcin